# How to create an invoice in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, invoice

The only thing i need is to add the company name on the top and also today's date but everything else is working for me now.  The user is able to select specific rows and export the selected rows in pdf but i need the company name on the top please help.  thanks

```
 protected void ExportToPDF(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


      using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
      {
        using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {

          //Hide the Column containing CheckBox
          GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
          foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
          {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
              //Hide the Row if CheckBox is not checked
              row.Visible = (row.FindControl("chkSelect") as CheckBox).Checked;
              // pnlBtn.Visible = true;
            }
          }

          GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
          StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
          Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A2, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
          HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
          PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
          pdfDoc.Open();
          htmlparser.Parse(sr);
          pdfDoc.Close();

          Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
          Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.pdf");
          Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
          Response.Write(pdfDoc);
          Response.End();
        }
      }

    }
```

Comment: If I read right, you've got a Grid written into HTML converted to PDF and sent to the client. So, what/where do you have a problem? Have you failed in adding a row with name/date into the Grid? Have you failed in adding a div or text to the intermediate HTML? Have you failed in configuring PdfWriter to add page headers? Have you tried these things so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to write the title before rendering the gridview.

```
hw.Write("<H1>This is my title</H1>");
GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
```